# Detect Element using ng-class in protractor

Tags: protractor, ng-class

Hi I have an element with class and ng-class attributes, ng-class contains the information of my element(an event created dynamically), i need to verify if event is created on correct date or day. [This is how my event looks like on page](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6edFW.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
element(by.id('1993')).getAttribute('ng-class').then(function (ngClass) {
     var date = new Date().getDate(); //to get today's date
     expect(ngClass).toContain(date);
});
```

Comment: Thanks that helped with a little change, in my case id is also dynamic value, but to help solving the issue I requested dev team to add a title attribute (static) for all elements and detected it successfully.. Thanks again for your response.

Comment: you can add `name` attribute for that purpose

Comment: No need to resolve the promise: `expect(element(by.id('1993')).getAttribute('ng-class')).toContain(new Date().getDate())`.

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/jx346vtg/  This filter is not working if i have multiple elements with same title, and i want to filter the one which has current date in ng-class attribute.

Comment: Thanks @Danny, this is what i was looking for, but this console.log(filteredElements) statement is printing a very long lis of objects on console.

Comment: the returned element has the entire `div` in it. Its always like that. you can do operations on it directly,No need to worry about the console.log() output

Comment: can i use filtered element out of this function, to be more precise i want filter to return an element which i want to use in another function to perform some actions.

Comment: thanks @Danny. How can I get count of the elements that are passed with filtering criteria . I am writing a code like this https://jsfiddle.net/u75h8ors/ but it is returning count as null. can you please help?

Comment: i have modified a bit according to your style. https://jsfiddle.net/u75h8ors/1/ . Bit i suggest you to use filter